# How to re-draw (refresh, update, replace) container in GTK3?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I need update some GTK container after some signal.

Let's imagine we have a `Gtk.Box`. Inside we have a `Gtk.Button` and a `Gtk.Label`. After clicking on the `Gtk.Button`, the previous content should be deleted, and a new `Gtk.Button` should be inserted in the same `Gtk.Box`.

Code example on Python:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        button1 = Gtk.Button("_OLD_")
        button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button_click)
        self.box.add(button1)
        self.add(self.box)
        self.show_all()

    def on_button_click(self, button):
        for child in self.box.get_children():
            child.destroy()
        button2 = Gtk.Button("_NEW_")
        self.box.add(button2)
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```

The problem is: new object `button2` doesn't add to `self.box`. May be because of this box was already added to another container (`self` in example)?

So what I need: The possibility to replace content in a GTK container, which already was initialized and displayed.

Comment: There should be a 'show' function you can use.  Though I would think it easier to simply change the button's label, and have the click handler determine which button was activated and process as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, you're right. To display added elements, each of them should be previously .show(), even child elements of container. So if we added box2 with 10 labels to box1 - it doesn't enough to .show() box2 - each label must be .show() too. It's strange method, but it's working, thank you!

Comment: @ntfs1984 look at widget instance method show_all -> box1.show_all().  to show box including all childs

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here is one way to do it:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        button1 = Gtk.Button("_OLD_")
        button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button_click)
        self.box.add(button1)
        self.add(self.box)
        self.show_all()

    def on_button_click(self, button):
        # The button that triggered the handler (i.e. button1) is
        # removed from the container.
        self.box.remove(button)

        # A new button is created and added to the container in its place.
        button1 = Gtk.Button("_NEW_")
        self.box.add(button1)

        # The window is re-shown
        self.show_all()
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```